# Can anyone recommend a resource for monthly trade data for Mexico from before 2010?

Tags: international-trade, data-request

Can anyone point me to a resource where I can find monthly series data (specifically for 2003-2013) on Mexico's imports and exports in nominal (current) Mexican Pesos (MEP) including broken down by major industry?

I've found UN data and OECD, but am having trouble navigating the INEGI site (since my grasp of Spanish is limited to the colloquial).

Comment: You might post a link to the INEGI site in case anyone with sufficient Spanish wants to find where you should be.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look for a few places. Looks like the WTO have something relevant. I haven't looked at the dataset but hopefully it is useful. This only has annual trade. The World Bank also has some data also covers annual data.

http://imts.wto.org/CDS/gp/tsselection.aspx

I think this one has your answer. It has monthly data. Only 1000 records at a time but up to 5000 if you sign up. You will probably have to be a bit clever with your queries and then merge a few spreadsheets as well. Clunky interface but the data looks vast.

**http://comtrade.un.org/monthly/Main/Data.aspx**

Comment: Comtrade is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I've come so far is the [OECD StatExtracts](http://stats.oecd.org/#), which gave me data in current USD. I'm still hoping someone can come up with something better.

It took some fiddling because their MEI tables seemed to be wonky in chrome, and all I got was "an error occurred" until I start fiddling with the (invisible) table's layout.

Answer (score 0):

INEGI has a (new) English version of its site, where you can find trade statistics (and many other). The site is [here](http://en.www.inegi.org.mx/proyectos/registros/economicas/comext/). Whenever the statistics are not available in English, a link redirects to the Spanish version (for example, [here](http://en.www.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/temas/economia/comercio/tabulados/bcom01_2015_6_17.xls)), so you still get the data you want (luckly, technical words like imports and exports, sector, and so on are pretty similar in both languages).