# UK trade with biggest partners, by year

Tags: data-request, international-trade

I am working at [lists](http://countrystats.wikia.com/wiki/United_Kingdom_-_Germany_trade) [like](http://countrystats.wikia.com/wiki/United_Kingdom_exports_-_top_markets) [these](http://countrystats.wikia.com/wiki/United_Kingdom_imports_-_top_markets), filling them with numbers about UK's trade with it's biggest partners. The problem is, I can't find [such](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/uktrade/uk-trade/december-2014/stb-uk-trade--december-2014.html) [data](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/uktrade/uk-trade/december-2013/stb-uk-trade-december-2013.html) for the years before 2010. I know that the institution (Office for National Statistics - ONS) [changed it's website in 2009 or so](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Office_for_National_Statistics&diff=320580350&oldid=313240014), and maybe it has to do something with that, but I can't find the data on the older site also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone recommend a resource for monthly trade data for Mexico from before 2010?](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/283/can-anyone-recommend-a-resource-for-monthly-trade-data-for-mexico-from-before-20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [The OECD](https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=BTDIXE) has nearly the exact data you are looking for. I haven't figured out how to get it into a raw data dump. I am pretty confident that this problem has more to do with me than it does with the data available.
- [The WTO](http://imts.wto.org/CDS/gp/tsselection.aspx) holds similar quality information. I think somewhere a UK govt body is publishing this. Not sure where exactly though.
- [The UN](http://comtrade.un.org/monthly/Main/Data.aspx#) has everything you need but you need to sign up.

See this question for other trade related sources:

[Can anyone recommend a resource for monthly trade data for Mexico from before 2010?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/283/can-anyone-recommend-a-resource-for-monthly-trade-data-for-mexico-from-before-20)

Comment: Thanks. The UN doesn't have any yearly data? It's way too much work to add the monthly data.